# On OSX, why does /usr/bin/cpp not support stringification of macro arguments while gcc -E and clang -E do?

Tags: c, llvm, llvm-gcc

If I have the following code in foo.c

```
#define P(x) printf("%s\n", #x)

void main() {
  P(3 == 4);
}
```

Invoking gcc -E foo.c will output:

```
int main() {
  printf("%s\n", "3 == 4");
}
```

Notice that the # operator has stringified the literal for macro argument x. However, when I invoke /usr/bin/cpp, I get the following ... which is not expanded properly.

```
int main() {
  printf("%s\n", #3 == 4);
}
```

Comment: It's eerie how it goes from `4 == 3` to `#3 == 4`. Maybe you shouldn't download your compilers on April 1?

Comment: 3 == 4 is a typo on my part. I changed the code in between copies of the output.

Comment: My /usr/bin/cpp is not llvm's preprocessor but gcc with the llvm backend.

Comment: Using Xcode (4.3) to show the preprocessed source file works for me.

Comment: Your code seems to work just fine for me when I compile it with `clang`. What happens if you use `clang -E` to run its own preprocessor?

Comment: @GregHewgill, clang -E works just fine. No idea why that would be inconsistent.

Comment: I have a recently-built llvm-3.0 with clang, and there is no `cpp` binary produced in the build. I don't know what `cpp` you're running.

Comment: `cpp --version` gives "i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.1.00)"

Comment: I think @NikolaiRuhe's comment suggests that my question should be reworded as LLVM is probably a red herring here. I'm actually asking why cpp and gcc -E differ in their handling of macros.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like for some reason, the `cpp` on Lion (I have the same version as you) behaves as though the `-traditional` switch is enabled. I can reproduce the output you observed on other `cpp` binaries (Linux, FreeBSD), but only when using the `-traditional` switch.

After investigating this, it turns out that `/usr/bin/cpp` on Mac OS X is a script that starts out like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Transitional front end to CCCP to make it behave like (Reiser) CCP:
#       specifies -traditional
#       doesn't search gcc-include
```

There is apparently no way to undo `-traditional` with another option once it is specified by this script. One workaround is to use a specific installed version, such as `cpp-4.2`. Using `cpp-4.2` on my system produces the desired expansion.

Comment: CCCP? I knew the russians were somehow involved in this!

Comment: Thanks @Greg, I should have occurred to me to see if `/usr/bin/cpp` was a script.

Answer (score 11):

The `cpp` command is probably not behaving as a conformant C preprocessor but as a legacy pre-ANSI C preprocessor. My guess is that Apple made it work that way because Darwin is a BSD system and some broken legacy BSD software using the `cpp` command for *non-C purposes* (like macro processing for config files) would break in subtle ways if you dropped in a conformant C preprocessor in its place.

In any case, the `cpp` command should not be used since you never know what you'll get. `c99 -E` is the POSIX conformant way to invoke the C preprocessor, and `$CC -E` is probably the right way to do it in a Makefile.

Comment: +1 - To add to the pre-ANSI `cpp` fun, here's a note by someone who found out that OS X `cpp` doesn't strip C++ style `//` comments: http://code.google.com/p/pycparser/wiki/CppOnMacOSX

Comment: There are times on SO when I wish I could downvote downvoters.

Comment: I'm guessing it was an Apple fanboy who was unhappy with my mildly harsh language about how `cpp` was intentionally broken for legacy compatibility...